# CASE with hyperlink formula in THEN not loading and sometimes bringing an error (the prob is not stable, data studio is buggy)

Tags: looker-studio

I have a "link" column where some cells are links and some are blank.

```
  link
1 https://www.mydomain.com.br/[code]
2 
3 https://www.mydomain.com.br/[code]
4
...
```

I only want to display a hyperlink in a table if the link exists, so I'm trying to create a new field using the following formula:

```
CASE
    WHEN 'https' IN link THEN HYPERLINK(link,'link available')
    ELSE ""
END
```

It is quite hard to identify where exactly is the problem since Google Data Studio is still very buggy.
Sometimes I get an error saying something like `"you can't use formulas on THEN clauses"`. Other times it accepts the code, however when I try to add it as a dimension in a table I get an error.

Is the formula wrong? How could I adapt it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original Post: Display a URL in a Table

To display the visible values as URLs, at the *Chart-level* ([Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)) - how about:

1. Setting the `link` *Field Type* to `URL`
2. Changing the *Missing Data* values from the default (`Show "Null"`) to `Show " " (blank)`

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f44e5e9d-ef12-4597-98fe-76030391e26c) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]

## Update: `HYPERLINK` Function

Expanding on the original post - Displaying a label on the URL can be achieved using a *Chart-level Calculated Field* - the [`HYPERLINK`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7431836) function:

```
HYPERLINK(link, "link available")
```

Added a [New Page to the Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f44e5e9d-ef12-4597-98fe-76030391e26c/page/a3zSB) as well as a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]